# Pergola post placement

Tags: pergola

I have contracted someone to build a pergola. The posts are 6x6 and placed oddly due to the back yard dimensions.

The issue I have is that the post were set on Sunday and the braces were removed on Wednesday. My contractor is saying because the braces were removed that the far post has moved four inches. I am not sure if this could be correct.

I think that the post was put in not square. Any assistance would be nice.

I have new concrete poured around all posts, they are saying they might have to cut out the post and reposition it.

My question is: can a post move four inches, after the braces were removed three days after construction, or were they put in incorrectly from the beginning?

Comment: The concrete would harden enough in hours that the post would not move. It sounds like the contractor is trying to dodge responsibility

Comment: Who removed the braces? I agree with @Ack  that the concrete would harden within hours.

Comment: There's an outside chance that the post dried and curved between the time it was set in concrete and now. Regardless of how it got to where it is, the post being out of plumb is entirely on the contractor's shoulders and they have an obligation to make it right.

Comment: Use a straight edge (a long ruler or level or even just your eyeball) to see if that post is straight. If it hadn't dried sufficiently before being installed, it could have warped while it was standing there, or it may well have been warped before it was installed. Is the contractor trying to charge you extra to replace the post, or just telling you that it needs to be done? If he's just notifying you, then let him go to it & don't worry.